# PHP/SQL inserts into middle of table?

Tags: php, mysql

Recently, I had to modify my php.ini file for the first time to change `allow_url_fopen`, but my particular web host needed me to create a new php.ini to modify any of its default settings. So I did, and all it contains now is `allow_url_fopen = 1`, and all was well with the world.

But now I'm getting weird behavior when inserting new rows in my MySql table. I did not change any PHP or SQL related to this, but now when I insert a new row, it is inserted somewhere in the middle of the table, rather than at the end of the table. I've been using the same code for months now and it's been working fine up until now.

Could creating a new php.ini file have messed with these preferences somehow? Searching through the internet turned up with absolutely nothing.

Edit: There is a rather clear pattern now: Rows by ID are being placed like this at the end of the table:

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 300 |
| 301 |
| 302 |
| 320 |
| 319 |
| 318 |
| 317 |
| 316 |
| 315 |
| 314 |
+-----+
```

...and so on.

Comment: have you made primary auto increment id for table?

Comment: Yes, I have done this

Comment: OK then what is the new inserted row ID ?

Comment: @meh sometimes mysql insert rows in the deleted part of table, anyway the id is incremented but the row is in the middle.

Comment: All the rows with IDs through about 1-300 are in order on the table. The most recent 30 rows or so are sprinkled randomly through the table.

Comment: Can you give us an image describing it?

Comment: @JoelRummel you can use an `ORDER` statement to retrieve data ordered, by `ID` in this case.

Comment: Actually there is a pattern. There are a few random placements, but for the most part, the rows are now being placed backwards, in a way... I'll edit the question

Comment: @Alex yeah... I could do that but it would be... inconvenient

Comment: @Alex but it is impossible if you delete id=4 it will not set inserted row id to 4 in the future. because of this feature we set column type for big tables to big int

Comment: @meh it will not replace the id with the same id, but will replace the ordered row in 4th place, with an `id=42535` for example.

Comment: @JoelRummel this has happened to me, in 2 cases, either for deleted rows or inserting data manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort them by clicking on ID in phpmyadmin or for a resort try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ORDER BY `id` ;
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about that query. It would still be interesting to learn what is causing this.